# Why $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong \oplus_i \mathfrak{m}^{i}/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$ as a $k$-vector spaces under some conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, p.327 and some question arises.

In the page, he argues as follows :

Let $k$ be a field and $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be a finite $k$-scheme. Then $X$ satisfies the equivalent properties of 5.20.

[image]

Thus we have $A= \prod_{x\in X}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, where $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local finite-dimensional $k$-algebra.

Let us denote by $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Then we have

$$ \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong \oplus_i \mathfrak{m}^{i}/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$$

as $k$-vector spaces.

**Q.1** And why this isomorphism is true? My first attempt is to show that $\operatorname{dim}_k\oplus_i \mathfrak{m}^{i}/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1} = \operatorname{dm}_k\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ And I stuck at some part of calculation of the dimension. Note that since $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is artinian ( $ \because \operatorname{dim}X=0$), $\mathfrak{m} \supseteq \mathfrak{m}^{2} \supseteq \cdots$ stabilizes so that there exists $n$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \supseteq \mathfrak{m} \supseteq \mathfrak{m}^{2} \supseteq \cdots \mathfrak{m}^{n} \supseteq \mathfrak{m}^{n+1} = \mathfrak{m}^{n} = \cdots$.

So, note that

$$\operatorname{dim}_{k}\oplus_i \mathfrak{m}^{i}/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1} = \operatorname{dim}_k(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}) + \operatorname{dim}_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{2}) + \cdots + \operatorname{dim}_k (\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}/\mathfrak{m}^{n}) + \operatorname{dim}_k(\mathfrak{m}^{n}/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1})(=0) + 0 + \cdots = \operatorname{dim}_k\mathcal{O}_{X,x} - \operatorname{dim}_k\mathfrak{m}^{n}$$

(True?)

And issue that annoying me is the appearence of the term $\operatorname{dim}_k\mathfrak{m}^{n}$. Can any one rescue from this embarrassing situation?

**EDIT** : I think that we may use the Nakayama Lemma to guarantee that $\mathfrak{m}^{n}= 0 $. Does it works?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: O. K. I upload image as a reference~

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\mathfrak{m}^n = 0$ combines both Nakayama's Lemma together with topology. The ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is local, of finite-type, defined over $k$, so it is a local Noetherian ring. In such a ring one necessary has that $\bigcap_n  \mathfrak{m}^n = 0$, and since it is Artinian we can conclude that some power of $\mathfrak{m}$ must be equal to zero.

So why does $\bigcap_n \mathfrak{m}^n = 0$? If we regard $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ as a module over itself then we can define the $\mathfrak{m}$-topology. The "*Artin-Rees Lemma*" says (reallly a consequence of this lemma), that the subspace topology on $\mathfrak{m}$ and the $\mathfrak{m}$-topology on it are the same. If we are willing to accept that the two natural topologies on this subspace $\mathfrak{m}$ are equal then $I = \bigcap_n \mathfrak{m}^n$ is the intersection of all neighborhoods of $0$ in the $\mathfrak{m}$-topology. However, $\mathfrak{m}I$ is also open, since the two topologies are equal, and we conclude that $\mathfrak{m}I = I$, and now by Nakayama's Lemma we can conclude that $I = 0$.

Comment: Uhm..Thanks. Now I think that we can use the Nakayama's Lemma more directly to show $\mathfrak{m}^{n} = 0$, since 1) $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is local noetherian ring, 2) so $\mathfrak{m}$ is the (finitely generated) Jacobson radical of the $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. 3) and $\mathfrak{m} \mathfrak{m}^{n} = \mathfrak{m}^{n+1} = \mathfrak{m}^{n}$. True? I think that your discussion seems to be going around a bit. Nevertheless, It seems like a worthwhile discussion. Anyway, in your argument, how can we deduce that $\mathfrak{m}I= I$? :)

Comment: The condition that $\mathfrak{m}I = I$ is where the topology comes in. Since $I$ is, by definition, the smallest neighborhood of $0$. Now, there are two topologies we can put on $I$, the subspace topology, and the $\mathfrak{m}$-topology, these two topologies are equal, so the smallest neighborhood of $0$ is the same, i.e. $\mathfrak{m}I$ is open in one topology, so it is open in the other topology, but since it is already the smallest neighborhood of zero they must be equal.

Comment: Since the ring is artinian you hace m^n = m^(n+1) for some n, as the powers of the maximal ideal stabilize, and the. Nakayama tells you that m^n is zero.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez : Yes, O.K.  ~